# removing ", + and similar characters via google sheet script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-macros, google-apps-script-editor

I have cells like

```
"Apple"
=+Organe +is +good
"Mango"
```

I want to remove all the characters i.e. `=` and `"` and `=+`

Tried `=SUBSTITUTE(C3,"+" ,"",1)` but didnt work

I am using Google Sheets and can't use Excel (in MAC)

Any google script experts?

Comment: "Substitute replaces existing text with new text in a string." The second line is an equation not a string.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this formula:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A1,"\W+"," ")
```

Result:

[image: Screensot]

If you only want to replace specific characters, use the "or" operator and list them:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A1,"[""|+|=]"," ") //will match quotes, plus and equal sign
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to string multiple substitutes in a single formula:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(C3, "=+", ""), """", ""), "+", "")
```

The first removes "=+", the second a double quote, and the third a "+" symbol

If you want to remove everything but a-z, A-Z and space this is much easier:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(C3, "[^A-Za-z ]", "")
```

Comment: Thanks but not picking up phrases like =best +apple is +needed

Comment: @user3415869 That would just mean adding another substitution function call. Use this formula: `=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(C3, "=+", ""), """", ""), "+", ""), "=", "")` and the phrase you just described should be properly *cleaned up*. Does this solve your issue?

Comment: =+hello +world +bye 

This would not process

Comment: how about removing the = sign first and then the others. or may be some google script?

Comment: basically i just want to display A-Z or a-z and not anything like numbers or symbols

Comment: but the good thing is the the symbols are just =, =+, " and + (not others)

Comment: @user3415869 for the proposed `=+hello +world +bye`, using the formula I commented, the result is `hello world bye`. Is this not what you expect?

Comment: added a regex example that should suit your needs better